# is it possible to define 'plot panels' in opengl and directly draw to them instead of the window?

Tags: opengl, panel

I was wondering whether the following can be easily implemented in OpenGL:

1. divide window into multiple panels
2. put each panel into place using normalized coordinates (0-1) so that if the window gets re-sized, the panel will stay in the correct position
3. draw directly into one of the previously defined panels

The result should look something like the following picture:

[image]

So far I've been drawing my objects directly into the window, offsetting the coordinates with the respective value for each panel. However this doesn't feel like the right way of doing things. Any suggestions and example code from experienced developers is highly appreciated!

**EDIT:** What I've read so far, using `glScissor` or `glViewport` might be two ways of accomplishing what I want, however I don't know what the pros and cons are for going either route (your insights are very welcome!). Additionally, I would really prefer to define some kind of `panel`, return its handle and just draw into that.

Comment: Are the windows a fixed size in pixels, or do you want them to resize with the window? If they resize, do you want to reposition stuff inside them or do you want them to simply stretch?

Comment: @Thomas the main window starts with a fixed size but it is re-sizable. Each panel is something like `1/num_panels *100 %` high and ~ 90% wide. if the main window get resized, the panels should keep their respective percental size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `glScissor()` you just define the clipping rectangle (i.e. where to draw). This might be everything you need.
With `glViewport()` you essentially call `glScissor()` behind the scenes as well as changing how coordinates are mapped to screen space.

If you want to limit drawing to one of the panels (without using local coordinates), use `glScissor()`. Otherwise, use `glViewport()`.

As for the panel, I'd probably use some abstract base class:

```
class Panel {
    // ...
    virtual void OnDraw(void) = 0;

    void Draw(void) {
        glViewport(x, y, w, h);
        OnDraw();
        glViewport(0, 0, parent_w, parent_h);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I don't quite understand the "If you want to limit drawing to one of the panels (without using local coordinates)" part. What do you mean by local coordinates? Ideally, for each panel I want to be able to pass absolute coordinates for the objects that need to be drawn (so each panel is basically treated like a new window)

Comment: That would be what I'd consider relative (or local) coordinates. If you want the corner of the panel to be e.g. (0, 0), then use `glViewport()`. Using `glScissor()` coordinates would still be the same (you'd just clip the pixels being drawn).

Comment: is it possible to define my panel location by using normalized coordinates? It seems to be like `glViewport` requires absolute coordinates. However, if I could use normalized coordinates (0-1) then the panel would always stay in place and resize with the parent window. Is that possible?

Comment: You'll have to calculate and update the screen coordinates to be passed to `glViewport()`, when resizing the window. Don't think there's a way to use normalized coordinates here (just for the parameters; actual drawing will use whatever you set). As an alternative, you could render your panel to a texture and then draw that texture to the panel position using a quad.